# VBA to delete multiple RangeNames for single Range

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have searched for an answer for hours, and can't search anymore.  Have Seen lots of discussions about deleting all range names from a workbook or a worksheet.  However, I need to delete multiple Range Names from a single Range while leaving other Range Names for other ranges on the same sheet and/or within the same workbook alone.  Might the code look something like this?:

```
Sub Delete_My_Named_Ranges()
   Dim nName As Name
   Dim wbk As Workbook
   Dim Sht As Worksheet
   Dim rgNm As Range, aCell As Range

   Set wbk = Workbooks("testRgNmDelete.xlsm")
   Set Sht = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

   Set rgNm = Sht.Range("$A$1")

        For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names
            Set aCell = Range(nName)
            If Not Intersect(aCell, rgNm) Is Nothing Then
                nName.Delete
            End If
         Next
  End Sub
```

OK, the above code works for a fixed range ("$A:$1").  But I need to be able to set rgNm as a variable instead of as a fixed range.  here is an example, the error now is on the statement "Set aCell = Range(nName)."

```
Private Sub cboProductType_Change()


Dim wbSKUM As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsLUL As Worksheet, wsLU As Worksheet
Dim rgPTL As Range, rgTable1 As Range, rgA1 As Range, rgA1LU As Range
Dim rgNm As Range, rgFormula As Range, aCell As Range
Dim sFormula As String
Dim nName As Name

Set wbSKUM = Workbooks("XBS_SKU_Master.xlsm")
Set ws = wbSKUM.Worksheets("SKUMaster")
Set wsLUL = wbSKUM.Worksheets("LookupLists")
Set wsLU = wbSKUM.Worksheets("Lookup")
Set rgPTL = wsLUL.Range("ProdTypeLookUp")
Set rgTable1 = ws.Range("Table1")
    sFormula = "=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(F2,"" "",""_""),""-"","""")"


 'clear Product Type Lookup List (Column D) to be sure no data remains
 wsLUL.Activate
 Range(Range("F2"), Range("F2").End(xlDown)).Select
 Selection.Cells.Value = vbNullString
    Set rgNm = Selection

    For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names
            Set aCell = Range(nName)
            If Not Intersect(aCell, rgNm) Is Nothing Then
                nName.Delete
            End If
    Next
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Comment: @LostInData, you shouldn't change your post in the way you did. You completely changed what you had started with and it could completely change the logic of all the answer provided by anyone. Your questions could be helpful for others, too, even you were wrong at the beginning. It's better to start new question if you are going next step of your problem.

Comment: Sorry.  been trying as hard as i can to figure out how to use this site.  maybe it's too advanced for me.  I'll drop out.

Comment: @LostInData, please, don't give up. Sharing problems it's best way for you to develop your skills, moreover, unintentionally you help others who could have similar problem one day. Finally, we do our best to help 'cause we like it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error becuase you have not set `rgName` after declaring it.

Here is my understanding of your question.

Lets say there is a Range `A1:A10` in `Sheet1` and Cell `A2` has a name `NM1` and Cell A5 has a name `NM2` and cell D10 has a name `NM3`

And you want a piece of code which deletes the Names in Range `A1:A10` i.e `NM1` and `NM2` and not `NM3`

If the above is what you want then try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rgName As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim nName As Name

    Set rgName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Set aCell = Range(nName)
        If Not Intersect(aCell, rgName) Is Nothing Then nName.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

And if I have misunderstood your question then you might want to rephrase it?

**FOLLOWUP**

> This has been an extremely useful site to me as a new VBA user, but I have ABSOLUTELY no idea how to add to this site, beyond these little notes. Please try to imagine the Name Manager in Excel 2010 - in Name Manager there are say 10 unique names, all for =Sheet1!$A$1. I want all of these names which pertain to Sheet1!$A$1 to be deleted by VBA code. I DO NOT want other names to be deleted anywhere. – LostInData 3 mins ago

Based on your above comment try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim nName As Name

    For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        If nName.RefersTo = "=Sheet1!$A$1" Then nName.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cell (or range) F2 contains many names, and i need all of these Range Names to go away.  I DO NOT want any names for other ranges or cells to go away.            FYI, i use this range to contain temporary lists.  Each time a user makes a different selection from the User Form, this list gets recreated.  the result is the Range gets renamed over and over.  Forgive me for having a lack of creative ways to explain this, but I need VBA code that will eliminate all of the Names for this specific Range, while leaving other Range Names unchanged.            Thanks again!

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean by Cell F2 has many names?

Comment: I clearly don't know how to use this site.  when i click Enter, my post gets uploaded but i'm actually just trying to create a new paragraph.  no idea how to post any examples   - is there a How-to-use-this-site section that I'm overlooking?

Comment: You can upload a screenshot to any image uploading sites and then share the link here. I will then upload that image in your question.

Comment: This has been an extremely useful site to me as a new VBA user, but I have ABSOLUTELY no idea how to add to this site, beyond these little notes.                Please try to imagine the Name Manager in Excel 2010 - in Name Manager there are say 10 unique names, all for =Sheet1!$A$1.   I want all of these names which pertain to Sheet1!$A$1 to be deleted by VBA code.  I DO NOT want other names to be deleted anywhere.

Comment: it's stuck in a loop.         current code reads:  Set rgNM = Selection (the selection being the range in question)   For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names   If nName.RefersTo = "rgNM" Then     nName.Delete    End If    Next

Comment: BTW i have to identify the range as a variable instead of a fixed range because the number of rows always varies.  The Column is always a single column.        thanks again.  I know there has to be a way!  :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something missing in the solution given above.

In order to refer to the range of a named range with the range object you must use the name property of your named range. Therefore, not `Set aCell = Range(nName)` but rather `Set aCell = Range(nName.Name)`.

Like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim rgName As Range, aCell As Range
    Dim nName As Name

    Set rgName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10")

    For Each nName In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Set aCell = Range(nName.Name)
        If Not Intersect(aCell, rgName) Is Nothing Then nName.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```