# Delete all instances of a range name

Tags: excel, vba

Suppose I have a workbook with multiple sheets. There are many ranges with the name `Name1`, at the worksheet scopes and the workbook scope. I want to write a macro that goes through the workbook to delete all instances of `Name1`.

For example, I open the Names Manager and I see:

```
Name1, refers to: =Sheet1!A1, scope: Sheet1<br>
Name1, refers to: =Sheet2!D3, scope: Sheet2<br>
Name1, refers to: =Sheet1!A1, scope: Workbook
```

I want to delete all of the `Name1`s

Now, `Names("Name1").Delete`, at the workbook level, doesn't work. I think it just takes care of the globally scoped `Name1`. Is there a way to work with a collection of names corresponding to a particular name? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I can give you the answer but I would like you to try it first. I might have answered a similar question earlier as well. Here is what you have to do. Loop though the names and then delete them. Give it a try.

Comment: do you mean loop through workbook.worksheets?

Comment: No. [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689786/vba-to-delete-multiple-rangenames-for-single-range) is one link where I have demonstrated on how to loop through names in a workbook.

Comment: Okay so now I'm looping through Workbook.Names to see if there's a match. However, for the names defined on the worksheet scope, `nName.Name` (where nName is an element of Workbook.Names) is of the form `SheetX!Name1`. I need to extract the stuff after the "!". Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: use SPLIT()..................

Comment: You need to check if the name has "!" or not. It is very much possible that the name will not have "!" if the scope is `Workbook` so use `INSTR` to check if "!" is there or not. If it is not there then directly compare the name else use `split(nm.name,"!")(1)="name1"` to check if the name matches and then use `nm.delete`

Comment: or something like: For Each N In NS /
    If N.Name Like "*!Name1" Or N.Name = "Name1" Then N.Delete /
Next N

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: + 1 Yup that is also another way :)

Comment: I had exactly what Siddharth had before looking at thew new comments, then decided to go with Ron's since it seems more elegant. However, I'm running into a cryptic run-time error 424 "Object required" when the loop hits the 'local' worksheet names. `For Each nName in wb.Names / If nName.Name Like "*Name1" Then nName.Delete / Next`. I.e. it works fine through `Name1`, `Name2`, `Name3`, but throws an error on `Sheet1!Name1`. Any ideas?

Comment: Deleting items while looping through a collection can cause problems. Try looping backwords `For x=wb.Names.Count to 1 Step -1: ''check wb.Names(x)...`

Answer (score 1):

The following macro removes all instances of `Name1` from all open workbooks

```
Sub deleteName()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = wb.Names.Count To 1 Step -1
            If wb.Names(i).Name Like "*Name1" Then wb.Names(i).Delete
        Next i
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Note that we need to loop backwards through the collection of names. This is because if we try to do `For Each nName in wb.Names / If nName.Name Like "*Name1" Then nName.Delete / Next`, Excel/VBA gives unexpected results such as `Error 424 Object Required`. I'm not sure why this behavior occurs.

Comment: + 1 For solving it yourself :)